# Why I can't omit the () here?

Tags: perl

```
SaveImages @img_sources;
```

The above will report:

```
Array found where operator expected
```

Why can't I omit the `()` here?

Comment: I don't know. Where are you getting `SaveImages` from?

Comment: Always show a complete test script. This will often show the things that are causing the problem, like your lack of a declared subroutine named "SaveImages".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

because your SaveImages subroutine is declared after the call. Parentheses are not necessary if a subroutine is declared before the call.

example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my @ar = (1, 2);
fn @ar;
sub fn
{
    print Dumper \@_;
}
```

does not work, while

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my @ar = (1, 2);
sub fn
{
    print Dumper \@_;
}
fn @ar;
```

works.

This is an expected behavior and is pointed out in the camel book.

Answer (score 6):

Perl can parse calls to subroutines without parens when those have been previously declared (or defined). For instance:

```
sub SaveImages;

SaveImages @img_sources;
```

Answer (score 6):

From [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html):

> To call subroutines:
>
> ```
> NAME(LIST); # & is optional with parentheses.
> NAME LIST; # Parentheses optional if predeclared/imported.
> &NAME(LIST); # Circumvent prototypes.
> &NAME; # Makes current @_ visible to called subroutine.
> ```

Usually subs are not pre-declared in practice.  That's not usually a problem, as people are generally accustomed to using parens with programmer-created subs.

[Perl::Critic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl::Critic::PolicySummary) (A module that supports Damien Conway's model of Perltopia as set forth in Perl Best Practices) suggests the following treatments for subs:

- Prohibit ampersand sigils.
- Prohibit subroutine prototypes.
- Prohibit parens with built-ins.

One of the reasons for not using parens with built-ins is to make them visually distinct from program-defined functions, which traditionally DO use parens.  Since it's unusual to predeclare subs, and it's discouraged to use ampersand (because it alters how @_ may be treated), or prototypes (because, well, it's a long story), that leaves a very strong background for using parens with script-defined subs.

Answer (score 4):

Many good points here, just one more: see also the [`subs` pragma](http://p3rl.org/subs). Used like `use subs qw/SaveImage/;` before your function call (probably near the top with the other `use` calls) it should nicely predeclare your sub in a less obtrusive way.

Answer (score -2):

You can omit `()` with built-in functions (see [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html)) because built-in functions are keywords of the language and don't need parentheses to be recognized as functions.

Some imported functions (as `max` from `List::Util`), usually from core modules, may be called without parenthesis also.

If a subroutine is declared before being called, parentheses can be omitted too, although [Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735) (chapter 2, section 4) recommends to avoid it in order to distinguish between calls to subroutines and built-ins.

Comment: Note that Perl function prototypes **_are not_** the same thing as function prototypes in other languages (they're just named poorly). You probably don't want to use them, well, pretty much ever.  Also, -1: incorrect. You can omit parens with user-defined subs, provided that the sub is defined prior to where it's called.

Comment: parens would not be needed if you had declared the right prototype. You want `sub fn(@) { print @_; }` and I assumed you wanted to print the contents not the reference value correct :)

Comment: @Joel You're right. I was just testing and assumed it didn't matter. Thanks. Answer updated.